# How to update a table using trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables, t1 and t2.
I'm trying to make a trigger so that when t1 gets an update, I check if what was updated was t1.nStatus.

If t1.nStatus = 2, I need to set t2.bEnabled = 1 for all t2.customer_Id that are equal to t1.nId

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change AFTER UPDATE ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.nStatus = 2 THEN
        UPDATE t2 SET bEnabled = 1 WHERE t2.immobile_id = NEW.nId;
    END IF;
END;
```

The error I got:

> 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query: CREATE OR REPLACE trigger changeStatusImmobile after UPDATE on
>   immobile for each row begin IF NEW.nStatus = 2 then UPDATE select...
>
> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 5
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec Transfer Time  : 0 sec Total Time     : 0.146
>   sec

Have you some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change AFTER UPDATE ON t1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.nStatus = 2 THEN
        UPDATE t2 SET bEnabled = 1 WHERE t2.immobile_id = NEW.nId;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Got it: 
No query(s) were executed. Please enter a query in the SQL window or place the cursor inside a query.